# Write a python code to merge two list with the following condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

**If two list is having same number, then the final list should not have the number**

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: Please post a sample input with expected output. Also, your attempt so far and where have you gotten stuck.

Comment: How about you start to write the code and if you get you ask a specific question including the code?

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
ls=[1,2,3,4,5,5]
ls1=[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9]

common_elements=set(ls).intersection(set(ls1))

for i in common_elements:
    if ls.__contains__(i):
       ls.remove(i)
    if ls1.__contains__(i):
       ls1.remove(i)
       
final_ls=ls+ls1
print(final_ls)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your lists contains unique elements, consider using sets instead.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Comment: Add this as a comment, rather than an answer